# Set Windows default sound scheme using GPO

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy

We have 50 Windows 7 client computers in an AD OU for which we need to change the Windows Default Sound Scheme to `None`.

How can this be accomplished using Group Policy?

Answer (score 3):

For domain function level before 2012 go to `User > Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization` then there is a setting **Prevent Changing Sounds**.

If you rolled out the desktops without the theme set in advance (as default) then I would use the above GPO in conjunction with enabling the "Load a specific theme" setting (also in the Control Panel > Personalization node of Group Policy). Just make a theme that you want for all users to use then save it somewhere all users will have access to and then put in the UNC under that object.

Comment: prevent changing sounds only stops you from changing what's already set, you always first would have to set the sounds to none as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry`
Set the following registry key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes`
Value: `(Default)`
Data: `.None`

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows theme with no sounds and assign that theme via GPO.